# is it possible to fill a UIBezierPath with a pattern image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying do draw a rounded rect filled with a pattern image (the pattern image should be repeated to fill the rect), is there a way to do that using UIBezierPath?
Possibly I would like to add a shadow to the border of the rect.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there anything you tried already?

First thing that comes to mind would be:

```
UIImage *patternImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomePattern.png"];
UIColor *fill = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImg];
[path fill];
```

Another option would be to draw a rectangle that fits your path, fill that using your pattern color, and clip that using your path.

Comment: yes, that works. Now I'm trying to understand about the shadow

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:YOUR_UI_IMAGE] setFill]`?